# Computer MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, web

I'm creating a database to compare different motherboards with CPUs. I want the user to be able to see which motherboard is compatible with which CPU and the other way around.

I've run in to a problem. I've created three tables. One consisting of motherboard ID, name and socket. One consisting of CPU ID, name and socket. The last one is a junction-table consisting of a main ID, motherboard ID and CPU ID. I want to be able to select the motherboard ID and CPU ID from the junction-table and then compare the different socket posts to select which posts to display on the screen.

How do I select a post in one table via a junction-table?

Comment: Can you give us the create table statements? Any code you already have?

Comment: I'll try to find it, I'm using phpmyadmin.

Comment: What - in this context - is a "post"?

Comment: I want to select a post, for example all the sockets or all the motherboards.

Answer (score 0):

A generic query:

```
select m.id motherboard_id,
       m.name motherboard_name,
       m.socket motherboard_socket,
       c.id cpu_id,
       c.name cpu_name,
       c.socket cpu_socket
from motherboard m
join junction j on m.id = j.motherboard_id
join cpu c on j.cpu_id = c.id
where c.id = ? and m.id = ?
```

Edit `where` clause as required.